# Hyper-V manager on ubuntu

Tags: hyper-v

Is there any way to manage standalone hyper-v 2016 core server via ubuntu?
I just can't find any information about it :<

Comment: You mean as a Virtual Machine?

Comment: ???
I have standalone hyper-v 2016 core server in my company.
Right now I'm managing it via Hyper-V manager on windows 10.
Can I somehow install and use hyper-v manager on ubuntu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realise this is old, but for anyone that view's this question, you can't run Hyper-V manager on anything but a Windows machine, either Windows 10 or Windows Server. You can however install Windows Admin Center and manager not only Hyper-V but other OS functionality via a web interface.
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/manage/windows-admin-center/overview

Answer (score 0):

You may want to install OpenSSH Server using PowerShell. You can find some info here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_install_firstuse.
Then, open your Ubuntu Terminal and login:

```
$ ssh administrator@your_server_ip
```